# Are almost all classes widget in flutter, like TextStyle?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am confused at the fact that, are the classes like TextStyle, MainAxisAlignment are widgets or just some classes?

If they are not widgets, how can I distinguish them?

Comment: A widget has a build function, other classes usually don't

Comment: they're not widgets themselves but they are used as properties within widgets.

Comment: `MainAxisAlignment` is a enum

Comment: @Md.YeasinSheikh enum is a class.

Comment: yap, special kind of class for constant values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All widgets are class, but not all class are widget.

> Those who (class) extend `Widget` class is also a widget.

You can check [widgets-library.](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/widgets-library.html).

`StatefulWidget` or `StatelessWidget` can be called both widget and class.

If it is not directly extend the `Widget` class, you will find an ancestor doing it, e.g  `SingleChildRenderObjectWidget` or `MultiChildRenderObjectWidget`  extends the `RenderObjectWidget` which parent is `Widget`.

There are many classes which is not a widget , `DateTime`,`TextSpan`,`TextEditingController`, `Animation` ...

Answer (score 3):

```
///
/// [TestWidget] is a widget which extends [StatelessWidget] class.
/// [StatelessWidget] is a widget which is extended [Widget] class.
///
class TestWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ///
    /// [Column] is a widget which extends [Flex] class.
    /// [Flex] is a widget which extends [MultiChildRenderObjectWidget] class.
    /// [MultiChildRenderObjectWidget] is a widget which extends [RenderObjectWidget] class.
    /// [RenderObjectWidget] is a widget which extends [Widget] class.
    ///
    return const Column(
      ///
      /// [Column] has a property named [mainAxisAlignment] which is an enum of type [MainAxisAlignment].
      /// [MainAxisAlignment] is an enum which has 6 values.
      ///

      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        ///
        /// [TextStyle] is a class.
        ///
        Text("Test", style: TextStyle()),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Widget is just a kind of class. I will write some examples:

- Model classes: ProfileModel, CartModel, ProductModel... These model classes are used to store somebody's profile information, someone's cart information, a product is buscuit or frozen meat...
- Utility classes: contain some functions such as convert from string to int, convert from USD to Yen, format datetime...
- Widget classes: In Flutter, they may be a StatefulWidget class, StatelessWidget class... The purpose is UI display.

As I see, the frameworks nowaday use **component** styles, web or mobile applications are designed in components. Widget is a component, and it belongs to UI class.

Answer (score 3):

this is an example using `TextStyle` and `Text` widgets in Flutter.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return MaterialApp(
   home: Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(
       title: Text('TextStyle Example'),
     ),
    body: Center(
      child: Text(
        'Hello, Flutter!',
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.blue,
          fontSize: 24,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
   );
  }
}
```

In this example:

`TextStyle` is a configuration class used within the `Text` widget to define the style of the displayed text.
Text is a widget that displays a string of text on the screen.
The `TextStyle` class configures the appearance of the text displayed by the `Text` widget. In this case:

`color` sets the text color to blue.

`fontSize` sets the font size to 24.

`fontWeight` sets the font weight to bold.

While `TextStyle` itself is not a widget, it's crucial for specifying how the `Text` widget should display its content. The `Text` widget is the actual UI element that renders text on the screen, and `TextStyle` is used as a property to style that text.

Comment: TextStyle is a class. style is a named  argument. There is no property. While we send style to the class Text, it assigns it to the property style.